# Android call multiple buttons with single touch

Tags: android, button, layout, touch

I'm trying to make a really simple touch test for android. I made a simple table layout, with 2 rows and in each row with 2 Views. It fills the screen. I set an onTouchListener that changes the Views background color. The issue is that if I swipe through multiple elements only the first touched elements ontouch event gets deployed. Is there any way to have call a function (change the background color) on all the views I swipe through with a singe touch?

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/touch_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp">

        <View
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minHeight="1dp"
        android:minWidth="1dp">

        <View
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            />

    </TableRow>
```

and the onTouchListener set method:

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.touch_table);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if ( v instanceof TableRow) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow)layout.getChildAt(i);
        for ( int j = 0; j < row.getChildCount(); j++ ) {
            View w = row.getChildAt(j);
            //set touch_listener
            w.setOnTouchListener(
                    new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                            // Perform tasks here
                            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
            );

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code, what you have implemented yet?

Comment: I don't think there is any such method. One solution is to create gesture listeners and listen to swipe events on parent view.

Comment: I've updated the post with the relevant code samples

Comment: drulabs - My only problem is with that method to how to find out which child is under the current touch position.